# How to get $\mid y\Big[\frac{x}{y}\Big]-a\mid <\mid x-a\mid + \mid y \mid \quad x,y\in R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

The solution of a problem I had to work on states that :

> $$\mid y\Big[\frac{x}{y}\Big]-a\mid <\mid x-a\mid + \mid y \mid \quad x,y\in R$$

Where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$. 
I don't know to get this inequality... I only have : 
$$\mid y\Big[\frac{x}{y}\Big]-a\mid <\mid x + a\mid$$
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\left[\frac{x}{y}\right]= \frac{x}{y} - \left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\}$, where $\left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\} < 1$ is the fractional part.  Then apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: Oh yes I did not think about the fractional part, it works thanks !